# Data storage replication in hadoop vs snowflake in cloud

Tags: hadoop, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In hadoop, data is replicated thrice(default) for fault tolerance
For example: if input data is of 5 gb size, then data is replicated with 15 gb and after transforming that data is stored in other storage area(5GB).
Total(In hadoop) = 25gb

Then how data is stored and replicated in snowflake. Is there any storage replication in snowflake architecture compared to hadoop?
Snowflake = ?

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake itself does not replicate data, however, it uses cloud-vendor-specific object storage which typically provides multiple levels of replication (e.g. [S3 in Amazon AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/)  for AWS-hosted Snowflake regions). See also e.g. [section 4.2.1 in Snowflake's 2016 SIGMOD paper](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2903741).

If you're asking from the cost perspective, that replication is hidden from the user, and the "list price" is what the user pays. Note, that Snowflake charges for **compressed** data size. Depending on the data, that size can be lower or larger than the input size.